# SQL best solution for the delete operation on multiple relationships

Tags: sql, jpa

I would like to have a clarification on deleting the multiple relationship

I have a schema that has a table 'A' and other tables of schema, that refer to 'A' with the role (Cascade) on delete operation.

There are also tables which refer to 'A' and which also have other references to other tables of 'A', but in this case the elimination must have a null value.

```
CREATE TABLE A
(A_ID INTEGER PK
...
) 

CREATE TABLE B
(B_ID INTEGER PK
A_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
...
FOREIGN KEY A_ID REFERENCES A(A_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE C
(C_ID INTEGER PK
A_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
B_ID INTEGER
...
FOREIGN KEY A_ID REFERENCES A(A_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
FOREIGN KEY B_ID REFERENCES B(B_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
)
```

These multiple relationships cause me a problem on the role delete operation.

I would have two options:

The first, and take on the role cascade all relationship with 'A', but that means I have to create a function that when I have to delete values of table 'A', the other value reference with this table delete from the bottom up. In the future I might forget to add a new table.

The second solution and create a table of connection to their reporting obligations have null values:

```
CREATE TABLE C
(C_ID INTEGER PK
A_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
...
FOREIGN KEY A_ID REFERENCES A(A_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE C_B
(C_ID INTEGER PK
B_ID INTEGER PK
...
FOREIGN KEY C_ID REFERENCES C(C_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
FOREIGN KEY B_ID REFERENCES B(B_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

It involves the creation of several new bridging tables.

There is a different solution to this case?

I currently use Apache Derby and JPA for persistence